# Alternative to overflow-y in CSS?

Tags: css, overflow, hidden, visible

I'm creating a calendar and need to replicate the behaviour I would get with

```
overflow-x:visible;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

for browsers that don't support these css attributes. Is there some kind of workaround I can do? I don't just want to compromise and add in overflow:hidden for those browsers, since the client really wants this feature. Does anyone have any good ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: They are supported in Internet Explorer 6.x+, Firefox 1.5+, Safari, Chrome and Opera 9.5+. Are there other widely used browsers that don't support them?

Comment: No they don't (at least the combination above doesn't). Take a look at http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html for example.

Comment: Can we get a screenshot? It's difficult to understand your contraints without context. I'd put a white div under the calendar, with a high z-index, but if there's content that would be affected by this "masking" div, then my point is moot.

Comment: Take a look at www.queensfestival.co.uk/ed. What I really want is nice javascript scrolling in the calendar on the left.

Answer (score 5):

Here is someone who asks roughly the same question (overflow-x visible and -y hidden).
http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=68&t=116457

Someone named *Weirdan* says [*I'd say there's isn't any expected behavior because such style is unavoidably internally inconsistent*](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=68&t=116457#p607602), and shows an example where it is not clear (says Weirdan) whether the area to the southeast should be hidden or shown.

S/he also says that [*the effect you want is easily achieved by wrapping the outer div with another div and setting overflow-y on that div to hidden*](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=68&t=116457#p608277), and shows this example (I hope it's OK that I copy it to here?).

```
<style type="text/css">
#outer-wrapper {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
#outer {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  border:solid red 1px;
  overflow:visible;
}
#inner {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:green;
}​
</style>
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```