# css overflow-x hidden not working in nokia device

Tags: html, css, document-body

```
    body 
{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

this property is not supportd in nokia device. Kindly help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are links to some same question's solution, have a look

> this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953372/923426
>
> this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8267076/923426